iOS Firebase Crashlytics UnityFramework maybe Text To Speech related
I keep getting crashes in Firebase - AudioOut.cpp line XXX wordpos_thread(void*)
When I view the threads I can find the thread
com.google.firebase.crashlytics.MachExceptionServer
and the thread before that
          AXSpeech
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1808 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x5008 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x4f20 mach_msg_overwrite + 436
3  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x4d60 mach_msg + 24
4  CoreFoundation                 0x53f5c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5  CoreFoundation                 0x53600 __CFRunLoopRun + 1208
6  CoreFoundation                 0x52cd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608
7  Foundation                     0xc7e4c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 212
8  TextToSpeech                   0x27718 TTSCFAttributedStringCreateStringByBracketingAttributeWithString + 776
9  Foundation                     0xde718 __NSThread__start__ + 732
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x606c _pthread_start + 136
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x10d8 thread_start + 8

So I think the crash is happening when some invalid text is being sent to be read. But I have no idea how to find or fix this issue?
And I can't reproduce it
Any ideas would be very appreciated
Thanks
I've tried searching through the stack trace to look for anything relating to my code.
Have found nothing
